# injection script by using src tag

Tags: security, javascript-injection

Someone wants me to using this tag to get number of my page loaded and some information.

but I don't know, Could it be dangerous?

```
<img style="display: none;" src="https://www.******/Distribute/PopSell/5" />
```

for example, it could print a custom script or anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he will be able to count times get the url,your vistors ip,refferrs,time,browser some  information (normal) and same information wich he get from his website visitors

he can not (xss) your site put he able to view any image by control his url & script and just listen to your vistors count & normal information using in analaytics ..

here example to [use javascript in src](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Script_in_IMG_tags)

put the static url and do not worry

He can not run any code in your page without changing this link that you've already set by you and make sure that free of any code

Even if used redirection

To reserve and you can put added

```
<img class="no_borken" src="http://hisValidURL...">
<script>
    $('.no_borken').error(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/error.png');
    });

</script>
```